# Color Management Blender geared towards motion pictures ?

Tags: color-management

Made aware of Color Management options in Blender I am now diving somewhat deeper in Color Management in Blender. The manual tells me that OpenColorIO is used ...

OpenColorIO (OCIO) is a complete color management solution geared towards motion picture production with an emphasis on visual effects and computer animation.

So I understand that the color management of Blender is primarily geared towards motion pictures / video. Is this correct ? Is this the reason that the default for almost everything is sRGB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I understand that the color management of Blender is primarily
>   geared towards motion pictures / video. Is this correct ? Is this the
>   reason that the default for almost everything is sRGB ?

Yes, OCIO is designed for motion pictures, visual effects, and animation.

sRGB is merely a default, and the reasons for this default are largely historical with where Blender borrowed the configurations from.

CM in OCIO is based on the notion of Views and other output transforms that operate independently of the reference data. To fully understand why, how, etc. would require a vastly more complex answer than this simple question touches on.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Do you have maybe a link where I can read more of the concepts you are referring to ? For now I am "helped with your answer. I now understand some things of Blender better

Comment: @JanScherders See other comment. There are a few answers here that might help you as well. See the "Wide Dynamic Range" answer for example. Gather the puzzle pieces and ask where things confuse.

Comment: One more thing ;) Blender is not only used for motion but also to create stills (for instance architecture work). I understand the photographers have to live with the fact that the motion concepts prevail ?

Comment: There is nothing to "live with", as once you become fluent with the concepts you will understand why OCIO was designed, how it fits into place, and how ICCs are absolutely awful for photographic image manipulation.